# Unable to set Cookie in php

Tags: php

I am facing some issue to retrive cookie after shifted the hosting, currently I am using following syntax:

```
setcookie("CatID", $CatID, time() + 3600, "/");
```

```
$_COOKIE["CatID"];
```

Comment: It looks like you are doing it right? what's the error? Also, you may need to check with  **isset()** function before printing out what's there in PHP cookie.

Comment: _"after shifted the hosting"_ - have you checked the error log for any related "headers already sent" messages? Could be an issue of automatic output buffering being set to on on your old system, which prevented such an error there.

Comment: Thanks for providing such detailed informations about whats not working and the errors.

Comment: Thank you guys for you valuable support....!
My problem has been resolved.
I just rearrange my code by placing header and body content and its working fine.